# when i use .ToShortTimeString()....templates can only be used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ActiveDevice.LastUseDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Displays my date textbox as read only, which is fine, however it shows both date and time. I only want date so iv used .ToShortTimeString() with:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ActiveDevice.LastUseDate.ToShortTimeString(), new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

and I get the error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Anyone know how to resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Use textbox instead of textboxfor.

Comment: says cant convert lambda expression to 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Please use `>` for quotes instead of indented code block.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert formatted date with HtmlAttributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ActiveDevice.LastUseDate, new { @readonly = "readonly", @Value = Model.ActiveDevice.LastUseDate.ToShortTimeString() })
```

Comment: Really. Should be `@Value` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `TextBoxFor` (as well as other template extensions) needs an expression that refers to a model property, so that the model binder could serialize the data:

> Need to verify the expression is valid; it needs to at least end in
>   something that we can convert to a meaningful string for model
>   binding purposes

<sub>(Check out the relevant code in [`ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ModelMetadata.cs#L264))</sub>

---

There are several ways to solve this, one is adding `DisplayFormat` attribute to your model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]  //try this as well? maybe Orchard intervenes into rendering...
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime LastUseDate { get; set; }
```

And then you use the property as usual is the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ActiveDevice.LastUseDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: tried this in the model. not the actual page wont load. says 404. must be something to do with using orchard cms

Comment: had to change it to public virtual DateTime LastUseDate { get; set; }...its an orchard thing...but unfortunately still appears as 12/12/2012 00:00:00 on screen? thanks for replies...any ideas?

Comment: Don't understand why it needs to be virtual? Your problem can be completely elsewhere. Anyhow - try adding  `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and see if that makes a difference. I added that to the answer. But it's possible that Orchard overrides the rendering, then you may want to debug its code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from andreister I was able to solve the problem. Changing it to a 'textBox', removing the lamba, ad adding in the name of the textbox in quotes:

```
@Html.TextBox("LastUseDate", Model.ActiveDevice.LastUseDate.ToShortDateString(), new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: I'd recommend the type safe `For<..>` methods so that you can rely on the compiler for testing generated HTML names etc. See, `TextBoxFor(x => x.LastUseDate1, ...)` won't compile immediately, but `TextBox("LastUseDate1", ...)` will and you'd get the error only when you perform the operation or render the page. I guess you use it because `TextBoxFor` doesn't work for you for some reason, but you'll be better off identifying and fixing the actual problem rather than hiding in non-safe `TextBox` :)